# Android Development - GestureDetector.OnGestureListener or GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener

Tags: java, android-studio, android-event, android-gesture

I'm working on simple code to detect all the gesture like fling, scroll, etc and was going to implement the interface `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` for overriding its methods but I got to know that same could be done with `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`. As far as I know the `SimpleOnGestureListener` is a class which have implemented `OnGestureListener`, `OnDoubleTapListener` and `OnContextClickListener` interfaces and if I'm wrong correct me.

On Android Developer website page it is written -

> If you only want to process a few gestures, you can extend
>   `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` instead of implementing the
>   `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` interface.
>
> `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` provides an implementation
>   for all of the `on<TouchEvent>` methods by returning false for all of
>   them. Thus you can override only the methods you care about. For
>   example, the snippet below creates a class that extends
>   `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` and overrides `onFling()`
>   and `onDown()`.

I got few questions here,

1) Why to use `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` if we can implement `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` and other interfaces for using those methods too?

2) Is `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` same with no difference? It is made to simplify coding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of [GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html)

> A convenience class to extend when you only want to listen for a
>   subset of all the gestures. This implements all methods in the
>   GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
>   GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener, and
>   GestureDetector.OnContextClickListener but does nothing and return
>   false for all applicable methods.

If you only want to implement a few of the method (not all of them) `SimpleOnGestureListener` has default implementation that do nothing. This prevents your code from being cluttered by multiple methods that do nothing. From a functionality standpoint it does not matter if you use `SimpleOnGestureListener` or implement the interfaces directly.

**Source Code**

```
public static class SimpleOnGestureListener implements OnGestureListener, OnDoubleTapListener,
        OnContextClickListener {

    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    }

    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
            float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }

    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    }

    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onContextClick(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I don't have to add other methods like I have to do while using GestureDetector.OnGestureListener? I can add the only method I want?

Comment: That is exactly it. They can not put default methods on an interface. But you want still want the interface because that allows for multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation should look alike this:

```
public class MyOnGestureListener implements
        GestureOverlayView.OnGestureListener,
        GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener,
        GestureDetector.OnContextClickListener {
    @Override public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {return false;}
    @Override public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {return false;}
    @Override public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {return false;}
    @Override public boolean onContextClick(MotionEvent event) {return false;}
    @Override public void onGestureStarted(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {}
    @Override public void onGesture(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {}
    @Override public void onGestureEnded(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {}
    @Override public void onGestureCancelled(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {}
}
```